# I can't import java.util.Scanner

Tags: kotlin, runtime-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhmdI.jpg)

I using android studio. I download jdk. I can't understand this error. Can you help me? I can't import java.utill.Scanner

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There isn't an error in your image. Scanner is greyed out because it's apparently unused and your class name isn't in the dictionary. Please include the actual error you are seeing (not as an image :-) )

Comment: No when i use      val veri = Scanner('in')     there is an error.

Comment: I try it and it was an error

Comment: @AliÇağlarKoçer when you type in `val veri = Scanner('in')`, place the caret on the Scanner and press Alt+Enter to see available options. Select the "Import" one. That will import the Scanner into your class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.